# Javascript "pop" from object

Tags: javascript, object, iterator

I wrote the following code to "pop" a property from an object as if it were an array.  This looks like the kind of code that would get me slapped by more serious programmers, so I was wondering what is the proper way to do this:

```
// wrong way to pop:
for( key in profiles ){
    var profile = profiles[key];  // get first property
    profiles[key] = 0;            // Save over property just in case "delete" actually deletes the property contents instead of just removing it from the object
    delete profiles[key];         // remove the property from the object
    break;                        // "break" because this is a loop
}
```

I should have mentioned above, that unlike a true "pop", I don't need the objects to come out in any particular order.  I just need to get one out and remove it from its parent object.

Comment: Wrap the body in an `if (profiles.hasOwnProperty(key) {..` and loose the `= 0`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Delete the first property that was added to an object? This won't necessarily work, as the order in which properties are retrieved in a `for..in` loop is not guaranteed. Other than that you should be using `hasOwnProperty` to make sure it's not part of the prototype, and you don't need to do anything other than `delete` to remove a property from an object.

Comment: I think you mean to mimic the [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) array method, which removes (and returns) the ***first*** element in the array. [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the ***last*** element, as the push/pop array methods act as FILO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for( key in profiles ){
```

You should really declare `key` as a `var`.

```
profiles[key] = 0;            // Save over property just in case "delete" actually deletes the property contents instead of just removing it from the object
```

is unnecessary.  Delete doesn't touch the value of the property (or in the case of a property that has a setter but no getter, even require that it have a value).

If the object has any enumerable properties on its prototype, then this will do something odd.
Consider

```
Object.prototype.foo = 42;

function take(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    // Uncomment below to fix prototype problem.
    // if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) continue;
    var result = obj[key];
    // If the property can't be deleted fail with an error.
    if (!delete obj[key]) { throw new Error(); }
    return result;
  } 
}

var o = {};
alert(take(o));  // alerts 42
alert(take(o));  // still alerts 42
```

Comment: This should really be called `shift`, since it removes the first element instead of the last. I understand the OP misnamed his request - perhaps you can note that in your answer.

Comment: @jbyrd per "don't need the objects to come out in any particular order" maybe "take"?

Comment: Doh! I guess I should've read that part more carefully. Makes sense. In that case, "take" is not a bad idea!

Answer (score 75):

Nowadays you can simply use the spread operator with its Rest way:

```
const { key, ...profilesWithoutKey } = profiles;
```

Credit to [this blog post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/)

Comment: This extracts the first entry, but not `profiles[key]`.

Comment: @Friedrich it does extract `key`. please check again.

Comment: Oh, indeed. But `key` is static, while in the question it is a variable. An example would surely help. Also, real pop should deliver the value, which is possible as well `var {b: b, ...rest} = {a:1, b:2, c:3}`, returns `b = 1` and `rest = {a:1, c:3}`.

Comment: @Friedrich my code does exactly that, you don't need to specify `{key: key, ...rest}`.  
if `profiles = {key: 0, a: 1, b: 2}`, than after executing the solution you'll get: `key = 0` & `profilesWithoutKey = {a: 1, b: 2}`

Comment: I think the correct syntax should be something like `const {[key]: valueOfKey, ...profileWithoutKey } = profiles;` since in the OPʻs question the `profiles` object does not necessarily have a key named `key`, rather heʻs actually iterating over the object and "pops" the first key of the object.

Comment: @Friedrich actually this answer extracts `profiles.key`, not `profiles[key]`, which are quite different, and ironically the OPʻs intention from the example is actually indeed trying to extract the value of the first entry of the object.

Comment: @hellopeach you're *technically* right. But it could be argued that the problem evoked by the title of the question is common and expected, but the one given in the description is a bit of a surprise. Often, when popping elements from a hashmap, one should know which. Thus `obj.pop("foo")` or `key = 'foo'; obj.pop(key)`.

Answer (score 5):

Properties in an object are not stored in a stack so the basic concept won't work reliably (aside from the other issues mentioned in the comments above).

If you really need such a construct try something like this.

```
var ObjectStack = function(obj) {
    this.object = obj;
    this.stack=[];
};
ObjectStack.prototype.push = function(key,value) {
    this.object[key]=value;
    this.stack.push(key);
};
ObjectStack.prototype.pop = function() {
    var key = this.stack.pop();
    var prop = this.object[key];
    delete this.object[key];
    return prop;
};

var my_obj = {};
var my_stack = new ObjectStack(my_obj);
my_stack.push("prop1",val1);
my_stack.push("prop2",val2);

var last_prop = my_stack.pop(); //val2
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a8Rf6/5/

Comment: One problem with this implementation is that we are having a stack, but the internal array is public. Anyone can alter it in anyway, or even replace it with something else that is not an array at all.

Comment: Javascript is fundamentally dynamic. I can change `Array.prototype.length` if I choose. While it's possible to create a more complex implementation using a closure to conceal the internal stack, this is a learning example, and in practice that's a lot of extra code to protect you from yourself in a way that the native language doesn't anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Having studied all the comments and solutions above, I can offer a completely ready solution based on them:

```
Object.prototype.pop = function() {
    for (var key in this) {
        if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) continue;
        var result = this[key];
        if (!delete this[key]) throw new Error();
        return result;
    }
};

var obj = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3'
};

console.log(obj.pop()); // 1
console.log(obj.pop()); // 2
console.log(obj.pop()); // 3
console.log(obj); // Object {  }
```

Perhaps someone will come in handy ; )

---

PS. If you use the code I propose along with the jQuery library, you may encounter errors in the console. In this case, the option given below is appropriate:

```
function _pop() {
    for (var key in this) {
        if (!Object.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) continue;
        if (key === 'pop') continue;
        var result = this[key];
        if (!delete this[key]) throw new Error();
        return result;
    }
}

var obj = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3'
};

obj.pop = _pop;

console.log(obj.pop()); // 1
console.log(obj.pop()); // 2
console.log(obj.pop()); // 3
console.log(obj); // Object { pop: _pop() }
```

Answer (score 3):

Thus without loop and "function" noise, simply

```js
key = 'b'
profile = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

val = profile[key] 
delete profile[key]

console.log(profile, key, val)   // Object { a: 1, c: 3 } b 2
```

Or, with dynamic key unpacking following the comment from @hellopeach

```js
profile = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
key = 'b'
var {[key]: val, ...profile} = profile
// var {b: val, ...profile} = profile 

console.log(profile, key, val)   // Object { a: 1, c: 3 } b 2
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no "correct" order across browsers in what they give for a `for in` loop. Some do them in the order they are put in, other do it numerical indexes first. So there really is no way to do this without creating your own custom object

Answer (score 2):

A better approach instead of directly modifying the input array.
Eg.

```
let arr = [{label: "a"}, {label: "b"}, {label: "p"}, {label: "c"}] 
let newArr = arr.filter(p => { return p.label !== "p";});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to create the pop method like this: .

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pop',{
    writable: false
    , configurable: false
    , enumerable: false
    , value: function (name) {
        var value = this[name];
        delete this[name];
        return value;
    }
});
```

for some reason using just Object.prototype.pop = function ... breaks JQuery