# Update an object and combine properties together in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert an object below:

```
let obj = {startDate: '2015-08-03', startTime: '12:00AM'}
```

to

```
let obj = {startDate: '2015-08-03 12:00AM'}
```

What is the best way to do that in javascript?

**Update**

This is what I have currently

```
export default object => {
 let newObj = {};
Object.keys(object).forEach(item => {
    if (object[item] === '') {
        delete newObj[item];
    } else if (moment.isMoment(object[item])) {
        newObj[item] = object[item].format('YYYY-DD-MM');
    } else if (item === 'startTime') {
        newObj['startDate'] = `${newObj['startDate']} ${object['startTime']}`;
    } else {
        newObj[item] = object[item];
    }
});
return newObj; };
```

But problem is when I select time field first then the date it will render out as

```
startDate: "undefined 3:00AM"
```

What am I missing now?

Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. The steps are not complicated and the objective here is for you to show your attempts and people help you fix **your code** when it doesn't do what is expected

Comment: What is your browser limitation? Can you do this in ES6? Or do you need to have it work in ES5?

Also are you just after that one format of an object into the other format? Or can the original object have any number of properties and how do you know what to copy to the other?

Comment: You have (implicitly) chosen @Intervalia's answer. Thus, tick his answer as the correct one and ask another question. Be fair !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use ES6 try this:

```
let obj = {startDate: '2015-08-03', startTime: '12:00AM'}
obj = {startDate: `${obj.startDate} ${obj.startTime}`}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I integrated with my updates.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to to do that often. If it is so, I [would first add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42017097/4194079) a new property-like method; the well known method `pop` to all `Object`-instances (via their constructor's prototype). First doing

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pop',{
    writable: false
    , configurable: false
    , enumerable: false
    , value: function (name) {
        var value = this[name];
        delete this[name];
        return value;
    }
});
```

and finally,

```
obj.startDate += ' ' + obj.pop('startTime')
```

which makes `obj` be

```
{startDate: '2015-08-03 12:00AM'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer ... good to know for future that I can do it this way. But in the case of what I am doing, only a one use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a new variable

```
let newDate = obj.startDate + ' ' + obj.startTime
```

Then put it on your object like this.

```
let obj.startDate = newDate
```

Then you can delete the startTime property with:

```
delete obj.startTime;
```