# Is there a javascript object equivalent to python's pop() on dicts?

Tags: javascript, python, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a JavaScript equivalent of Python's {dict}.pop(). I see that JS has a shift() and pop(), but those are hardcoded for first and last positions in an Array. Is there an equivalent where I can specify the position for an Object?

Example of what I can do in Python:

```
>>> foxx = {'player':{'name':'Jimmie','last':'Foxx','number':3}, 'date':'2018-01-01', 'homeruns':3,'hits':4}
>>> player = foxx.pop('player')
>>> foxx
{'date': '2018-01-01', 'homeruns': 3, 'hits': 4}
>>> player
{'name': 'Jimmie', 'last': 'Foxx', 'number': 3}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript "pop" from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630772/javascript-pop-from-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in one instruction, but you can get the property and then use `delete` to remove the property from an object.

```js
let foxx = {'player':{'name':'Jimmie','last':'Foxx','number':3}, 'date':'2018-01-01', 'homeruns':3,'hits':4};

let player = foxx.player;
delete foxx.player;

console.log(foxx);
console.log(player);
```

So you could create some custom function that does these two operations in one go :

```js
function pop(object, propertyName) {
    let temp = object[propertyName];
    delete object[propertyName];
    return temp;
}

let myObj = { property1 : 'prop1', property2: 'prop2' };

let test = pop(myObj, 'property1');

console.log(myObj);
console.log(test);
```

There is probably a better way of writing this, suggestions welcome. (for instance, see [Martin Adámek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49847870/479251) for a nice implementation leading to the same python syntax)

Answer (score 7):

I do not think there is such a thing, also note that `shift` and `pop` are methods of `array`, not of an `object`.

But you could polyfill that yourself easily:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'pop', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
  writable: false,
  value: function (key) {
    const ret = this[key];
    delete this[key];
  
    return ret;
  }
});

var foxx = {'player':{'name':'Jimmie','last':'Foxx','number':3}, 'date':'2018-01-01', 'homeruns':3,'hits':4}
var player = foxx.pop('player')
console.log(foxx, player);
```

Answer (score 3):

With a custom function:

```
function pop(obj, key) {
    var val = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern way of doing this in js is using the rest operator(3 dots) but still not changing the original object in place.

```js
let obj = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
const {key1, ...objNew} = obj;
console.log("key1", key1);
console.log("objNew", objNew);
```

The above snippet causes the new `objNew` object to only contain `key2` and a new variable `key1` will contain the value contained in the `key1` property of `obj` object.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53912486/11769765

```js
foxx = {'player':{'name':'Jimmie','last':'Foxx','number':3}, 'date':'2018-01-01', 'homeruns':3,'hits':4}

var {player, ...foxx} = foxx

console.log(foxx)
console.log(player)
```