# How to get a property from a JavaScript Object while removing it at the same time

Tags: javascript, performance, object, javascript-objects

I have this Object

```js
firstObject = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4 
};
```

and I want to create a new Object with some of its values while removing them to use both later.

```js
firstObject = {
  'a': 1,
  'c': 3
};
```

```js
secondObject = {
  'b': 2,
  'd': 4 
};
```

Which is the proper and more efficient way to do this? I have seen things like this but I was wondering if there is some kind of `.pop()` method like [the Array one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) but for Objects.

```js
secondObject['b'] = firstObject['b'];
secondObject['d'] = firstObject['d'];

delete firstObject['b'];
delete firstObject['d'];
```

Comment: No, there is no method to read and remove

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a javascript object equivalent to python's pop() on dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847788/is-there-a-javascript-object-equivalent-to-pythons-pop-on-dicts)

Comment: there's no way you can get and remove the properties from an object _at the same time_

Comment: @Abhishek. Thanks! that answered my question. Also the answer from Jacob was really helpful and clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One sneaky trick for doing this is to use destructuring:

```
const { b, d, ...rest } = firstObject;
Object.assign(secondObject, { b, d });
firstObject = rest;
```

Essentially, the `...rest` in the destructuring is for creating an object with all properties not previously destructured.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob! That answered my question and the code is pretty clean!

Answer (score 0):

I'd make an array of the properties you want for one of the new objects, then use `Object.fromEntries` to construct the new object from those keys. You can create the other object by `.filter`ing the object's entries by whether the key being iterated over exists in that array:

```js
const input = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4 
};
const props = ['a', 'c'];
const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(
  props.map(prop => [prop, input[prop]])
);
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input)
    .filter(([key]) => !props.includes(key))
);
console.log(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: this is way more code and far more expensive than just "get and then delete" though? (`['b','d'].forEach(prop => { s[prop] = f[prop]; delete f[prop]; })` would make more sense)

Comment: If one has an arbitrary number of properties, it's much more maintainable to be able to list the properties one wants for an object in an array than to repeat them multiple times on multiple lines. `delete` also has horrible performance implications (though that's rarely a significant concern) and is usually a code smell IMO

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with a simple loop and delete.

```js
firstObject = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4 
};

secondObject = {}

function copyToAndDelete(first, second, props) {
  props.forEach(function (key) {
    second[key] = first[key]
    delete first[key]
  })
}

copyToAndDelete(firstObject, secondObject, ["b", "d"])

console.log(firstObject)
console.log(secondObject)
```